# Google Sheets add a Permanent timestamp

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am setting up a sheet where a person will be able to check a checkbox, in different times, depending on the progress of a task. So, there are 5 checkboxes per row, for a number of different tasks.

Now, the idea is that, when you check one of those checkboxes, a message builds up in the few next cells coming after. So, the message is built in 3 cells. The first cell is just text, the second one is the date, and the third one is time.  Also, those cells have 5 paragraphs each (one per checkbox).

The problem comes when I try to make that timestamp stay as it was when it was entered. As it is right now, the time changes every time I update any part of the Google Sheet.

I set u my formulas as follows:

For the text message:

```
=IF($C4=TRUE,"Insert text 1 here","")&CHAR(10)&IF($E4=TRUE, "Insert text here","")&CHAR(10)&IF($G4=TRUE, "Insert text 3 here","")&CHAR(10)&IF($I4=TRUE, "Insert text 4 here,"")&CHAR(10)&IF($K4=TRUE, "Insert text 5 here","")
```

For the date:

```
=IF($C4=TRUE,(TEXT(NOW(),"mmm dd yyyy")),"")&CHAR(10)&IF($E4=TRUE,(TEXT(NOW(),"mmm dd yyyy")),"")&CHAR(10)&IF($G4=TRUE,(TEXT(NOW(),"mmm dd yyyy")),"")&CHAR(10)&IF($I4=TRUE,(TEXT(NOW(),"mmm dd yyyy")),"")&CHAR(10)&IF($K4=TRUE,(TEXT(NOW(),"mmm dd yyyy")),"")
```

And for the time:

```
=IF($C4=TRUE,(TEXT(NOW(),"HH:mm")),"")&CHAR(10)&IF($E4=TRUE,(TEXT(NOW(),"HH:mm")),"")&CHAR(10)&IF($G4=TRUE,(TEXT(NOW(),"HH:mm")),"")&CHAR(10)&IF($I4=TRUE,(TEXT(NOW(),"HH:mm")),"")&CHAR(10)&IF($K4=TRUE,(TEXT(NOW(),"HH:mm")),"")
```

And it all looks like this:
[image]

I would appreciate it greatly if anyone could help me get this to work so that date and time are inserted after checking those boxes and they don´t change again

Comment: Then you need AppScript coding. Formula can't make it permanent.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your struggle with the continuous changing date time. I had the same struggle as yours over the year, and I found a solution that works for my case nicely. But it needs to be a little more "dirty work" with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

Some **background** for my case:

- I have multiple sheets in the spreadsheet to run and generate the
  timestamp
- I want to skip my first sheet without running to generate timestamp
  in it
- I want every edit, even if each value that I paste from Excel to
  generate timestamp
- I want the timestamp to be individual, each row have their own
  timestamp precise to every second
- I don't want a total refresh of the entire sheet timestamp when I am
  editing any other row
- I have a column that is a MUST FILL value to justify whether the
  timestamp needs to be generated for that particular row
- I want to specify my timestamp on a dedicated column only

```
function timestamp() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const totalSheet = ss.getSheets();

  for (let a=1; a<totalSheet.length; a++) {
    let sheet = ss.getSheets()[a];
    let range = sheet.getDataRange();
    let values = range.getValues(); 

    function autoCount() {
      let rowCount;
      for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        rowCount = i
        if (values[i][0] === '') {
          break;
        }
      }
      return rowCount
    }

    rowNum = autoCount()

    for(let j=1; j<rowNum+1; j++){
      if (sheet.getRange(j+1,7).getValue() === '') {
        sheet.getRange(j+1,7).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Explanation**

1. First, I made a `const totalSheet` with `getSheets()` and run it
   with a `for` loop. That is to identify the total number of sheets
   inside that spreadsheet. Take note, in here, I made `let a=1;`
   supposed all JavaScript the same, starts with `0`, value `1` is to
   **skip the first sheet** and run on the second sheet onwards
2. then, you will notice a function `let sheet = ss.getSheets()[a]`
   inside the loop. Take note, it is not supposed to use `const` if
   your value inside the **variable is constantly changing**, so use
   `let` instead will work fine.
3. then, you will see a `function autoCount()`. That is to make a `for`
   loop to count the number of rows that have values edited in it. The
   `if (values[i][0] === '')` is to navigate the script to search
   through the entire sheet that has value, looking at the row `i` and
   the column `0`. Here, the `0` is indicating the **first column** of the
   sheet, and the `i` is the row of the sheet. Yes, it works like a
   `json` object with `panda` feeling.
4. then, you found the number of rows that are edited by running the
   `autoCount()`. Give it a `rowNum` variable to contain the result.
5. then, pass that `rowNum` into a new `for` loop, and use `if (sheeet.getRange(j+1,7).getValue() === '')` to determine which row
   has not been edited with timestamp. Take note, where the `7` here
   indicating the **7th column** of the sheet is the place that I want a
   timestamp.
6. inside the `for` loop, is to `setValue` with date in a specified
   format of `("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")`. You are free to edit into any
   style you like
7. ohya, do remember to deploy to activate the trigger with event type
   as `On Change`. That is not limiting to edit, but for all kinds of
   changes **including paste**.

Here's a screenshot on how it would look like:

[image: First Column Value 7th Column Timestamp]

Lastly, please take note on some of my backgrounds before deciding to or not to have the solution to work for your case. Cheers, and happy coding~!